# Best approach to configure a class in JS

Tags: javascript

I am working with ECMAScript 6 and I bumped into a specific issue and I have no idea what approach to use.

I have my JS class and I want to call that class from a template with some specific variables.

For now - it is solved by providing an object with a configuration such as:

```
MyController.bind({
       service: {
            key: 'a1b2c3d4e5f6',
            element: '#service_input'
        },
        selectors: {
            search: '.searcher',
            details: '.details',
            data: '.data',
            find: '.find',
            form: {
                line1: '#form_line1',
                line2: '#form_line2',
                city: '#form_city',
                postcode: '#form_postcode'
            },
        },
        data: {
            line1: 'line1data',
            line2: 'line2data',
            city: 'citydata',
            postcode: 'postcodedata'
        }
    });
```

But this approach creates so much mess. It's way too many parameters there.

So, What should I do?

Comment: "so much mess" is what I would call "Appropriate code". I dont see the problem here!?

Comment: Whats problem here. I think its neat code only. There is only one parameter that is json string. You can  store json string in variable and pass it as argument.

Comment: @TavishAggarwal Javascript object literal != JSON string

Comment: What I mean is create a JSON variable. Parse string to json, store it in variable and pass it to function.

Comment: @TavishAggarwal but *why*? You dont need a string if you already have an object literal. Its just overhead for no appreciable benefit

Comment: Maybe only to make your function calling neat.. :-D
I couldn't see any problem in this approach

Comment: @Jamiec to play devil's advocate, one benefit would be separation of concerns, but in this specific case, I don't think that's necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way you can do is:

```
    var configObject = {
       service: {
            key: 'a1b2c3d4e5f6',
            element: '#service_input'
        },
        selectors: {
            search: '.searcher',
            details: '.details',
            data: '.data',
            find: '.find',
            form: {
                line1: '#form_line1',
                line2: '#form_line2',
                city: '#form_city',
                postcode: '#form_postcode'
            },
        },
        data: {
            line1: 'line1data',
            line2: 'line2data',
            city: 'citydata',
            postcode: 'postcodedata'
        }
    };

MyController.bind(configObject );
```

Apart from this I cannot able to see any improvement in this code.
**NOTE:** This improvement is also not necessary, but you can do it to keep your code clean

Comment: Sorry to be pedantic, but once again that is *not* JSON. It is an object literal. Apart from that this is a perfectly good idea - separate out the definition of the object from the use of it *does indeed* make the code clearer.

Comment: @Jelean Does it answer your question?

Comment: @TavishAggarwal I was looking into a different (or standard) approach for passing arguments into a class, but it seems that this is the best one. (due to your comments and replies). I don't think this is the right answer, because it's just throwing object into variable... But yea, I think it is answered. Thanks guys.